# VBA run time error 438

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am trying to write a code to open a PPTX file from excel VBA and update links in ppt.

below is the code that i have got but while the code is trying to update links i am getting the

> Run time error 438 Object does not support this property or method

```
Sub kunal()

Dim PPObj As Object

Set PPObj = CreateObject("PowerPoint.application")

With PPObj      
    .Presentations.Add

    .Presentations.Open Filename:="Y:\Desktop\Month End\One_Shot\Template AVP Report Package\ABD-OME SDeeson.pptx"

    .Visible = True    
    .UpdateLinks    
    .Presentation.Save

    .Quit    
    Set PPObj = Nothing    
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Kunal. It would seem to me that are getting this error because your are setting `PPObj` to `Nothing` while you are still using it in your `With` statement. Why don't you try to move the line `Set PPObj = Nothing` **after** the line `End With` and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

438 means that you are trying to access a property of a method or object, that does not exist. Thus, you need a presentation object and not application object to update the links.

Try like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub kunal()

    Dim PPObj As Object
    Dim pptPresentation As Object

    Set PPObj = CreateObject("PowerPoint.application")
    Set pptPresentation = PPObj.presentations.Open("C:\test.pptx")

    With PPObj

        .presentations.Add

        .Visible = True
        pptPresentation.UpdateLinks
        pptPresentation.Save
        pptPresentation.Close

        .Quit
        'Set PPObj = Nothing - No need for this
    End With

End Sub
```

[Application Object MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/application-object-powerpoint)

[Presentation Object MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/presentation-object-powerpoint)

Comment: Thanks for the code. This was really helpful and very sill of me.  I wanted to check one more thing. Is it also possible that i can do the same thing for multiple ppt that are saved in the same location by applying loop or something.

Comment: Yes, you can open, update and close (save) many files in the same directory by using  F = Dir(direct, 7)  'sets f equal to the first file name
Do While F <> ""

Answer (score 0):

**First**, not sure why you need `.Presentations.Add` if at the following line you are opening an existing Presentation.

**Second**, the line of `.UpdateLinks` is a property of the `Presentation`, not the `PowerPoint.Application`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub kunal()

Dim ppApp As Object
Dim ppPres As Object

Set ppApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.application")

With ppApp
    .Visible = True

'    .Presentations.Add ' <-- not sure why you need to open a new Presentation ?
    Set ppPres = .Presentations.Open(Filename:="Y:\Desktop\Month End\One_Shot\Template AVP Report Package\ABD-OME SDeeson.pptx")

    ppPres.UpdateLinks
    ppPres.Save
    ppPres.Close

    .Quit
End With

Set ppPres = Nothing
Set ppApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I've got a page on my PPTFAQ site that will probably help with this:
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00536_Batch-_Do_something_to_every_file_in_a_folder.htm